# How to capture HTTP communication from TFS client using Fiddler

Tags: tfs, fiddler

I have a sample project where, using TFS Client lib (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll among others), I query builds.

```
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection
                                                              (new Uri(tfsServerName)))
{        
    var bs = tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();
    var buildSpec = bs.CreateBuildDetailSpec(teamProject, buildDefinitionName);
    buildSpec.InformationTypes = null;
    buildSpec.MinFinishTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    buildSpec.Status = BuildStatus.Succeeded;
    var buildDetails = bs.QueryBuilds(buildSpec).Builds;
}
```

I want to capture and analyze the outgoing HTTP traffic when running that code.
Using Wireshark I see that the DLL makes regular HTTP POSTs to the server.

**Fiddler however doesn't see that traffic. How do I change that?**

Thing that works:

doing a similar call myself

```
new WebClient().DownloadString("http://tfs03te:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Build/v4.0/BuildService.asmx");
```

Things I've tried:

Setting GlobalProxySelection (yes, it's obsolete)

```
GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

Setting TFSPROXY environment variable

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TFSPROXY","http://127.0.0.1:8888");
```

Setting the proxy in app.config

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
     <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="False" 
            proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="False" />
 </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

Setting the proxy in registry under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy
```

I set

```
Enabled = True
Proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

None of the above did the trick.

Analyzing decompiled TFS Client

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.PrepareWebRequest()
```

I see that it bypasses the proxy only if an appropriate setting tells it to

```
if (settings.BypassProxyOnLocal && BypassProxyOnLocalHelper.IsHostLocal(webRequest.RequestUri.Host))
{
    webRequest.Proxy = null;
}
```

(additionally the server is not even local)

Other than that it doesn't seem to modify that Proxy value after the request has been created with TfsHttpRequestHelpers.PrepareWebRequest (which deeper inside uses the default from WebRequest.InternalDefaultWebProxy).
But I must have missed something, because it still bypasses the proxy (i.e. Fiddler).

In Fiddler I've checked all the usual suspects:

- It captures traffic from "All Processes"
- Acts as system proxy on startup
- Monitors all connections
- It listenes on 8888
- "Use PAC Script" is unchecked but toggling it doesn't change anything
- Options -> Gateway -> Use System Proxy is selected

In WinINET settings 127.0.0.1:8888 is entered as the proxy for HTTP (that's done automatically by Fiddler)

If it's not possible with Fiddler, is there any other way to dump raw HTTP requests from TFS client?

Answer (score 2):

Your server *is* local, according to the `BypassProxyOnLocalHelper`, which defines a local host as one which is not fully qualified.  If your host is specified as `tfs03te`, without a domain, then it is local.

Simply specifying `tfs03te.mycompany.com` will make your host eligible for proxying.

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. I used the IP address instead and it worked. Thanks!